# Deactive iOS 9 Safari Content Blocking from within the app?

Tags: swift, safari-content-blocker

I am searching for a way to easily deactivate the safari content blocking from within the app. Any idea how to do this? Can `SFContentBlockerManager.reloadContentBlockerWithIdentifier` be helpful for this?

Comment: hi bro, got any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are displaying data inside `SFSafariViewController` it's impossible, because Enabling/Disabling iOS9 Content Blocker is a User Settings. 
As far as I understand it, Content blocker doesn't affect `UIWebView`.

During beta `reloadContentBlockerWithIdentifier` worked in Simulator, but didn't work on real devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can "kinda" disable safari content blocking by providing `NSItemProvider` with no rules in the `ContentBlockerRequestHandler`.

Whenever user enables/disables content blocking in the main app you can sync this state with the extension e.g. using shared container `UserDefaults(suiteName:)` in the `App Group` and call `SFContentBlockerManager.reloadContentBlockerWithIdentifier`

Of course, the extension will have to stay enabled in Settings.